# SQL Server Transactional Replication with highly referenced Objects failes at reinitialisation

Tags: sql-server, database, replication, object-reference

we have a Database Replication set up where we Replicate all Tables of a Database to multiple Production Servers.

There are also Views, Stored Procedures, Functions, etc. in the Database which are manually deployed to the Replicates through TSQL Scripts.

Now if for example a new table is added to the Publication, we have to reinitialize all Subscriptions by creating a new snapshot and let it deliver through the Distributor (which is on the same server as the Publication). The Headache starts when the Distribution Agent wants to drop the Table to recreate it afterwards, some Tables are been referenced by views, which have also been referenced by another objects. the Distributor cannot (or will not) drop the objects and runs into an error like `Cannot DROP TABLE 'dbo.table' because it is being referenced by object 'thisisafunctionorview'.`

In the past we also had the Views, Functions and StoredProcedures in the Publication but that caused even more Pain (Reinitialisation had to be done after each minor change on procedures, etc.), also then the reference problems where really frustrating.

To resolve this issue we have to drop all functions and views (in total about 200 Objects) and recreate them after the snapshot had been delivered.

Does someone have an idea how we could modify the concept of this replication that we could change objects and not having to set a massive downtime (about 2h for 6 Replicates) to fix the mess because of the references?

To complete the Information:
We use MS SQL Server 2008 R2 on all the instances (with Enterprise and Standard Editions). Upgrade to SQL Server 2014 is planned later this year for the Publisher and some of the Subscribers.
Only the Publication demands writing access.
Updates to the schema of the Database are deployed frequently (about twice a month) usually there are only changes in Procedures but sometimes there were tables added / modified, thats where our replication concept seems to falls apart.

Any suggestions are welcome
Thanks in advance!

Sincerely 
David

Comment: You might want to post this to http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds strange to me because I have a lot of stored procedures in replication and there is no problems with SP changes. ALTER PROCEDURE [can](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151870(v=sql.105).aspx) be propagated on subscriptions. Also I see no problems with subscriptions re-initialization because of objects dependencies. I can remember such problems in merge replication though, and there is SP to re-arrange objects. In most cases SQL Server handles dependencies well. Second note, you can add\remove articles to transactional replication [without re-initialization](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2502/limit-snapshot-size-when-adding-new-article-to-sql-server-replication).

I think if you re-create replication on test environment and play with it a little bit, you'll find a way how to replicate schema changes and don't do re-initialization too often. It is possible but requires some efforts.